# How to disable and enable div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm developing a shopping site in which I'm validating the address using zipcode during the checkout. I want to disable each div which is not deliverable.
Below, is the code

```
<?php
    if (isset($all[0])) {
        for($i = 0; $i <= count($all) ; $i++) {
            if (isset($all[$i])) {
?>
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                    <div id="addrs" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 addr-box" data-addr="<?php echo $all[$i]['id']; ?>">
                        <strong><?php echo $all[$i]['name']; ?></strong>
                        <?php echo $all[$i]['zip'] ?>
                        <?php
                            if ($all[$i]['zip'] && (in_array($all[$i]['zip'], $area['area']))) {
                                $availability = '<p>True</p>';
                            } else {
                                $availability = '<p>False</p>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $availability ?>
                </div>
<?php
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: same ids are in iteration, causes in an invalid markup.

Comment: What you meant by `disable each div` ?

Comment: The code you need is `$('#IDselector').hide()`. But check your html, as @Jai suggested, it is not valid

Comment: You mean by `disable` to hide the div or add an specific style?

Comment: @SherinJose I don't want that div to be clickable

Comment: @Jai Since I'm new to coding, I'm finding it difficult to understand. Can u plz post a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if (isset($all[0])) {
  for($i = 0; $i <= count($all) ; $i++) {
    if (isset($all[$i])) {
      $availability = ($all[$i]['zip'] && (in_array($all[$i]['zip'], $area['area'])));
      ?>
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-xs-12" <?php if(!$availability){ echo "style='pointer-events:none;'"; } ?> >
        <div id="addrs" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 addr-box" data-addr="<?php echo $all[$i]['id']; ?>">
          <strong><?php echo $all[$i]['name']; ?></strong>
          <?php echo $all[$i]['zip']; ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo "<p>".($availability ? "True" : "False")."</p>"; ?>
      </div>
      <?php
    }
  }
}
?>
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for, but this adds `style='pointer-events:none;'` to divs which aren't available, which should prevent them from being clickable.

Comment: Thanks. This is what expected. It worked. Jus one thing. How to apply a class instead of pointer-events

Comment: It's a minor modification: replace `<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-xs-12" <?php if(!$availability){ echo "style='pointer-events:none;'"; } ?> >` with `<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-xs-12 <?php if(!$availability){ echo "unavailable-class'"; } ?>" >`.